# Issues while using grails plugin "uml-class-diagram:0.4.4"

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use "`uml-class-diagram:0.4.4`" plugin to generate the UML diagrams and more likely I would like to generate class diagram and database diagram with it. But when I run the command "`grails uml-class-diagram`" in the grails command prompt, it gives following error. I've tried a lot but couldn't find solution.Please help if I'm doing anything wrong. I've declared it in `BuildConfig.groovy` as `runtime ":uml-class-diagram:0.4.4"`

```
Error |
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.UmlService.redirect() is applicable for argument types: (grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.ConfigurationCommand) values: [grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.ConfigurationCommand@366a72de]
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:733)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:774)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:572)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:471)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:422)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
Error |
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.UmlService.redirect() is applicable for argument types: (grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.ConfigurationCommand) values: [grails.plugin.umlclassdiagram.ConfigurationCommand@366a72de]
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:51)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at UmlClassDiagram$_run_closure1.doCall(UmlClassDiagram:16)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
Error |
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. It needs to install `Graphviz`. It is mentioned in the document. I missed to read that.